# Only calling a function when an optional is not nil in one expression?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-binding

I know it is possible to do this like so:

```
let intValue: Int? = rawValue == nil ? Int(rawValue) : nil
```

Or even like this:

```
var intValue: Int?

if let unwrappedRawValue = rawValue {
    intValue = Int(unwrappedRawValue)
}
```

However I'm looking to find out if there's a way to do this in one expression, like so:

```
let intValue: Int? = Int(rawValue) // Where Int() is called only if rawValue is not nil
```

Comment: you want if intValue is not nil to be assigned with the rawValue?

Comment: I want `intValue` to be `Int(rawValue)` if `rawValue` is not nil, otherwise if `rawValue` is nil I want `intValue` to be nil.

Comment: You can explicitly unwrap it if you are sure it's not nil but other than that your two ways do their job. May i ask what exactly you are trying to make? Or this is a generic question?

Comment: It's a generic question, I was just wondering if there's a more 'swift-y' way of doing it.

Comment: the most swifty way and the one most developers tend to use is the second one you wrote. The one with the if let statement

Comment: You can also have a look at optional chaining to get a bit more to the "heart" of optionals

Answer (score 5):

Similarly as in [Getting the count of an optional array as a string, or nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203541/getting-the-count-of-an-optional-array-as-a-string-or-nil), you can use the `map()`
method of `Optional`:

```
/// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
@warn_unused_result
@rethrows public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
```

Example:

```
func foo(rawValue : UInt32?) -> Int? {
    return rawValue.map { Int($0) }
}

foo(nil) // nil
foo(123) // 123
```

Answer (score -2):

So in order to answer your question and here you can have some optional cases as follows :
your first one:

```
let intValue: Int? = rawValue == nil ? Int(rawValue) : nil
```

your second one:

```
var intValue: Int?

if let unwrappedRawValue = rawValue {
    intValue = Int(unwrappedRawValue)
}
```

third case:

```
var intValue : Int?
if intValue !=nil
{
//do something
}
```

fourth case if you are sure the value is not nil

```
var intValue : Int?
intValue!
```

The last case will crash your application in case it's value is nil so you might use it for debugging purposes in the future. I suggest you have a look on those links for optional binding and optional chaining from apple's manual

[optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

[full apple guide for swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

and to finish with answering your comment section question most developers tend to use this method:

```
var intValue: Int?

if let unwrappedRawValue = rawValue {
    intValue = Int(unwrappedRawValue)
}
```

cause it seems to be the most type safe. Your call.