# Getting the count of an optional array as a string, or nil

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the count of an optional array as a string, or nil if the array is nil.

This works:

```
let array: [AnyObject]? = ...

textLabel.text = (array != nil ? String((array?.count)!) : nil)
```

But it looks ridiculous. Is there some nicer way to write this (still as a one-liner)?

**Edit**: I expect the text to be "`3`" not "`Optional(3)`", for example.

In Objective C, this could be `(array ? [@(array.count) stringValue] : nil)`.

Comment: sounds like optional chaining to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this:

```
textLabel.text = array?.count.flatMap { String($0} }
```

`flatMap` on an optional will return either nil (if the optional was nil) or the result of running the closure and passing the optional as the argument.

**Edit to surface other possible answers from the comments** —jrc

- `array.map { String($0.count) }` — [Kurt Revis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218876/kurt-revis)
- `(array?.count).map { String($0) }` — [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r).

Comment: Even better, just use map: array.map { String($0.count) }

Comment: Hmm, I get `Value of type 'Int' has no member 'flatMap'` on `count`.

Comment: His `array` is really an Optional<Array>, so array.map() means Optional.map not Array.map, doesn't it?  It worked for me in a playground, anyway.

Comment: For some reason unknown to me you need parentheses: `(array?.count).flatMap { String($0) }` (and `map()` would work as well, there is no difference in *this* case because the closure does not return an optional).

Comment: Thanks guys. `(array?.count).map { String($0) }` works and is even readable.

Comment: Ah right. Missed that you said array.map rather than array?.map. Subtle, but nice.

Comment: Oh. Sorry @Kurt Revis. Aha, I didn't know you could call `map` on optionals! Very cool. Thanks guys.