# Using Swift's optional binding to get NSData's bytes directly?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have the following code, assuming `data` is of type `NSData?`:

```
    if let myData = data {
        let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(myData.bytes)
        ...
    }
```

How do I reduce this to a single statement, such as:

```
    if let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>?(data?.bytes) {
        ...
    }
```

The above gives an error of: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>?' with an argument list of type '(UnsafePointer<Void>?)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly as in [Getting the count of an optional array as a string, or nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203541/getting-the-count-of-an-optional-array-as-a-string-or-nil), you can use the `map()`
method of `Optional`:

```
/// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
@warn_unused_result
@rethrows public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
```

In your case:

```
if let bytes = (data?.bytes).map({ UnsafePointer<UInt8>($0) }) {

}
```

`(data?.bytes)` uses optional chaining and has the type
`UnsafePointer<Void>?`. The map function is used to convert that
to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>?`, which is finally unwrapped with the
optional binding.